# should I change <html lang="en_US"> to <html lang="en">？

Tags: html

I used to think that if I want to target US audience I should use:

`<html lang=en_us>`

However, recently I got this message from https://validator.w3.org

`Error: Bad value en_US for attribute lang on element html: The language subtag en_us is not a valid language subtag.`

So is the `en_US` totally wrong? I should change all my html tags to `en` from `en_US` now?

Any detailed information on this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang

Comment: Should that not be "en-us"?

Comment: How about just `lang=en` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So is the `en_US` totally wrong?

It's not a valid value for that attribute. It should be `en-US` - [valid values](https://gist.github.com/JamieMason/3748498).

- [Declaring language in HTML](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations)